# Creating a 50 X 50 grid of patches in NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

In NetLogo, I would like to create a specific number of patches (e.g. a 50 x 50 grid).

Is there any means by which I can set the size of the environment?

Answer (score 4):

Above the space where the patches appear is a button labeled "Settings...", click that and then adjust the min/max pxcor/pycor to create an environment that is the size you wish. If you leave the location of the origin as Centre and then change max-pxcor and max-pycor to 25 each then you'll get a 50x50 grid.

Hint: If the environment comes out too big to fit onto your screen without scrolling change the Patch size to a smaller number - this will reduce the dimensions in pixels of each patch, so you'll fit more patches onto the same screen space.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at `resize-world` command documentation.